# Trouble Resizing Google Maps From A Hidden Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I've tried to avoid asking this question on here and I've searched and searched for a solution, but ultimately had no luck for my current problem. I currently have two input text fields that gets two separate locations and then displays it on a Google map. Ok, I'm able to do that but then I wanted the map to slide down from the top after a button is clicked which it does but now the height of the map is slightly larger than its original container and it's not zoomed properly, however, If I click that same button again without refreshing the page, the map then resets into its container and displays the route with no other troubles.

Note: before pressing the display button again the map has all kinds of resizing issues which can be seen in this pic:

[image]

From what I understand, I need call on

> google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

But I personally believe that I'm calling it in the wrong place before that map has time to load. I'm not fully sure what else to do so any help is appreciated.

My Javascript/jQuery (Displaying the map and trying to resize is at the very bottom):

```
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('address1'));
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('address2'));
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    'draggable': true
  });
});

function GetRoute() {
  var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: mumbai,
    styles: [{
      stylers: [{
        saturation: -100
      }]
    }]
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
  source = document.getElementById("address1").value;
  destination = document.getElementById("address2").value;

  var request = {
    origin: source,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

  //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [source],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
      var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
      var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
      var dvMiles = document.getElementById("miles");
      var dvTime = document.getElementById("time");
      dvMiles.innerHTML += "Distance: " + "<br />" + distance;
      dvTime.innerHTML += "";
      dvTime.innerHTML += "Duration: " + duration;

    } else {
      alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
    }
  });
}

$("#slide").click(function() {
  $("#dvMap").slideDown("slow", function() {
    document.getElementById('dvMap').style.display = "visible";
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  });
});
```

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Edit:

HTML:

```
<div id="dvMap">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dvMap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is `map` a global variable? If not, it might be not known to the function `$("#slide").click(function() {`

Comment: Yeah, it actually is a global variable as I have it outside of the GetRoute() function.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (including any required HTML/CSS)

Comment: How is this downvoted? I've provided the issue with the necessary code and even pictures of the problem. The HTML is an empty div.

Comment: ..Went ahead and added HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out what was wrong. So I had an empty div in my HTML but that div needed to be placed inside another div container like so:

```
<div id="dv">
  <div id="dvMap">

  </div>
</div>
```

It had nothing to really do with my JS, but you have to change the id names in JS:

```
$("#slide").click(function() {
  $("#dv").slideDown("slow", function() {
    document.getElementById('dv').style.display = "block";
  });
});
```